# Why the use of "dynamic" when reading OneDrive folder properties?

Tags: c#, onedrive

In the Microsoft documentation for C#/XAML (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631815.aspx), they have this as example code to get a folder's properties:

```
private async void btnReadFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.session);
        LiveOperationResult operationResult =
            await liveClient.GetAsync("folder.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!126");
        dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
        infoTextBlock.Text = "Folder name: " + result.name + ", ID: " + result.id;
    }
    catch (LiveConnectException exception)
    {
        infoTextBlock.Text = "Error getting folder info: " + exception.Message;
    }
}
```

Since I'm building up the code, I've replaced "infoTextBlock.Text" with a call to Debug.WriteLine but the compiler is giving me this warning:

The dynamically dispatched call to method 'WriteLine' may fail at runtime because one or more applicable overloads are conditional methods.

I've never used "dynamic" in my code so far so I'm struggling to understand why this keyword has been used and why WriteLine is failing (even if I build the string outside of the call to WriteLine).

I realise I won't be using WriteLine all of the time but if I don't understand why this is failing, I may hit other problems further down the line.

Can I do something other than use dynamic? Or can I do something to the code to stop the problem occurring with WriteLine?

Thanks.

Comment: type `dynamic` is not checked by the compiler, and it assumes that the object supports any operation. So it is logical the compiler generates a warning (i didn't find any documentation on this). check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd264736.aspx). I would suggest using @t3chb0t's suggestion.